# How to get billing address in Authorize.net using Subscription Id

Tags: authorize.net

We have used `updateSubscription` method of `Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) API`  of Authorize.net. We found that the billing details like credit card and billing address is updated properly in Authorize.net. As we are not storing any billing details in the  site we are fetching this data again from Authorize.net to display to the users. But we are not able find any API methods which will return these information.

Does any one know any other way to get this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already discovered, there is no API call to get subscription information other then a subscription's status. So if you intend to only use the ARB API then you will need to store this information in your database if you need to use it at a later time. Your other option is to use the Customer Information Manager (CIM) API which allows you to store *and* retrieve billing information. This, of course, would require using and paying for two APIs which shouldn't be necessary if you just store this information yourself.